# Paste from unique PasteBoard (app-specific pasteboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipasteboard

Im Saving to a **unique** pasteboard here:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard" create:YES];
[pasteboard setPersistent:YES];

//save to unique pasteboard
[pasteboard setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.myTextFieldHere]];
```

Trying to read it out here:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteSaved = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard"];

   _myTextFieldHere.text = [pasteSaved string];
```

My error is "no class method for selector" for my local variable of `pastesaved`

What ive tried so far

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteSaved =[[UIPasteboard pasteboardTypes] containsObject:@"myPasteBoard"];

 UIPasteboard *pasteSaved = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard"];

 UIPasteboard *pasteSaved = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName:@"myPasteboard"];

 UIPasteboard *pasteSaved = [UIPasteboard: @"myPasteboard"];

 UIPasteboard *pasteSaved = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it

It appears than when using a app specific pasteboard you need to add  if your creating a pasteboard or receiving from it using `create YES or No`

Copy to Pasteboard

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"myPasteboard" create:YES];
[pasteboard setPersistent:YES];

//save to unique pasteboard
[pasteboard setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.myTextFieldHere]];
```

Paste from Pasteboard

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"ICPatEditionPasteboard" create:NO];

   self.myTextFieldHere.text = [pasteboard string];
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have created your unique pasteboard, you paste items to it using the `addItems:` method:

```
[pasteboard addItems:@[ @"my_string_for_pasting" ]];
```

Alternatively,

```
[[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName:@"myPasteboard"] addItems:@[ @"my_string_for_pasting"];
```

**EDIT:**

To read from the pasteboard:

```
NSString *copiedString = [[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName:@"myPasteboard"] valueForPasteboardType:kUTTypePlainText];
```

Comment: What im after is how to paste items FROM  it