# IOS :Can I use custom URL scheme to communicate a flag between three applications should be always in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, flags, custom-url

can I  use Custom URL scheme  to communicate Data ( a  "flag" ) between three applications in background without make some of these applications in foreground  ?

I want communicate a flag between three applications(in the same device) always in bakground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a flag and both your applications are under the same teamid, you can use the pasteboard functionality to share data.

If the data is to be secure you can apply some encryption on this data and share the data.
You can use the following two links to share the data.
Just try to keep the name of the pasteboard as same.

http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

[Paste from unique PasteBoard (app-specific pasteboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606920/paste-from-unique-pasteboard-app-specific-pasteboard)

Comment: Thank you , the flag can be modify by these 3 apps ?  how to add my three applications in the same  teamid ?

Comment: IF these were created recently under the same developer account, then they have the option of this same id